# in facebook dev. app, I am trying to add privacy-policy link of website, getting validation error "couldn't follow redirect of this link"

Tags: facebook

**in facebook developer app, I am trying to add privacy-policy & terms pages links of website, but getting validation error "could not follow redirect of this link"**

I have created project app in my facebook developer account, now trying to add privacy-policy & terms pages links of website. But its giving validation error like "could not follow redirect to link"

My privacy-policy link like:

```
xyz.com/privacy-policy
```

**above link is with "https://"**

**above link is exist in my project**, but facebook giving issue

please suggest me the solution for this issue

Comment: See what the debug tool has to say about the URL, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Comment: getting issue during debug "URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed." @04FS why getting such issue

Comment: Because your server is doing a redirect for some reason. Without knowing the real URL we can't give you much help

Comment: @WizKid vahkart.com/privacy-policy .. with "https".. fb sharing debug tool showing issue to all pages.. it may be invalid page content?

Comment: Facebook is saying that your server is returning 307. Why your server is doing that I have no idea